# Merge content of two csv files in alternate rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have two CSV files
csv1:

```
header
a
b
c
```

csv2:\

```
header
e
f
g
```

I want to merge these two files to another CSV in alternate rows like
output.csv:

```
header
a
e
b
f
c
g
```

Can this be done? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes it can. Is the header in the output file the one from csv1 or csv2 ?
Are you going to process huge CSV files ?

Comment: In addition to question above: are the two files guaranteed to be equal length, and if not, should the "missing" items be ignored, or filled with a placeholder (None / Null / empty / certain string ? )

Comment: @fbattello Yes, header remains same. Both the CSV files will have around around 3 lakh rows each. Both the files wont be having equal number of rows.

Comment: @fbattello The missing items can be ignored.

Comment: Just to be sure. In your example if we add a `h` row to `csv1` output will remain the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will definitly not be the fastest way but it works

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain, zip_longest

x = pd.DataFrame()
x["header"] = [1, 3, 5, 7]

y = pd.DataFrame()
y["header"] = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 21]

chained = list(chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(x["header"].to_list(), y["header"].to_list())))
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["header"] = chained
df = df.dropna()
```

Comment: In `zip_longest` function you can pad with a different value than None by using the `fillvalue` parameter, then you wouldn't need to use `df.dropna`

Answer (score 1):

A more "traditional" Python approach that doesn't require any external dependencies.

```py
with open("csv1.txt") as f1, open("csv2.txt") as f2, open("output.txt", "w") as fo:
    csv1, csv2 = f1.readlines(), f2.readlines()
    header, _ = csv1.pop(0), csv2.pop(0)
    output = [header]
    for i in range(min(len(csv1),len(csv2))):
        output.extend([csv1[i], csv2[i]])
    fo.writelines(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming csv 1 read into `df1`

Assuming csv 2 read into `df2`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'header': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'header': ['d', 'e', 'f']})

print(pd.concat(
    [df1, df2], axis=1
).stack().reset_index(1, drop=True))
```

output #

```
0    a
0    d
1    b
1    e
2    c
2    f
```